# Excel 2016 vba editor, cannot open ThisWorkbook module

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel 2016 file (.xlsm). After few weeks working on this file, now I'm facing with one small but weird problem - cannot open ThisWorkbook module. As you can seen in the picture, trying to open this module, window just simply freezes on the screen, any mouse's single or double-clicks on it have no effect.

Maybe somebody also had the same issue? What might cause it and how to resolve it?

[image: ThisWorkbook module freezes on the screen]

Comment: Possibly corrupted file, sometimes you might have luck with trying to save a copy and opening that one instead.

Comment: If not already done reboot the machine and repair office. Next step if the previous did not resolve the problem. Looks to export module. here a reference   http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm

Answer (score 1):

this might have only worked for me but is worth a try

clear the office cache (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OfficeFileCache\0)

open the file on a different computer and name it something random.
open the file on the first computer and resave file.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in Han's comment, it's possible that the module is corrupted. You may be able to salvage it by right clicking the module and using 'Export File...' to save it as a class file.

If this succeeds you can attempt to recover your code by:

1. Importing the saved file, this will add 'ThisWorkbook' as a class file that can be opened like other modules.
2. If this doesn't work, try opening the saved file in Notepad. This should reveal your code in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I literally have this probablem every day or so. There is no answer, I have to save multiple files everytime I make any changes to the workbook. Its incredibly frustrating when all the macros disapear from the list and you can't open a single module

Answer (score 0):

This is the only similar problem I have seen that is similar to mine. I figured that if the only other example that has the same symptoms uses the same language of a small country as me (lithuanian), that this must be the corelation. And i was right, changing the office dispplay language to english(US) helped.It P.S. sorry for nekroposting this still hapening in 2023 on MS 365 so i asumed it is relevant for someoneone else.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).